# d3js zoom inline svg

Tags: d3.js, svg, zooming, inline

i am trying to apply D3js zoom to inline SVG. But somehow it does not want to work as expected. So far anything i find on the web is using just D3 which works fine when using its own logic of creation of the svg and then manipulating it. So i found a nice example on this link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RDgrINy7DkEBRD7pcWRD?p=preview

I want to get the same effect but with inline SVG. So following the example of the link above i created the code below which recreates my problem. Zoom only works when mouse over the element. Then when zoom out and try to pan the circles get out of the picture and cant come back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="D3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">
 <svg id="svg" width="600" height="600">
   <g>
    <rect width="600" height="600" style="fill: lightblue" style="opacity: 0.4"  pointer-events="all"></rect>
    <g>
      <g id='damnCircles'>
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20" style="fill: red"></circle>
        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="20" style="fill: red"></circle>
        <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="20" style="fill: red"></circle>
      </g>
    </g>
   </g>
 </svg>
 </div>
<script>

var zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
.on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
//  console.log(svg.attr('transform'));
   console.log(svg);
}

var svg = d3.select("#damnCircles")
  .call(zoom);
 </script>
</html>
```

Any help of hints of what am i doing wrong are appreciated!
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else got stuck on similar problem. I just figured it out :)

```
# here select the G element that contains the elements we want to transform
function zoomed() {
 var toModify = d3.select('#damnCircles')
    .attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

# here select the first G element under SVG as event listener.
var svg = d3.select("#svg").select('g')
  .call(zoom);
```

Now zoom and panning work as expected! Great!!